# SSIS 2012 with CozyRoc Data Flow task issue

Tags: excel, dynamics-crm-2013, ssis-2012

I am working on SSIS 2012 with CozyRoc for Dynamic CRM data imports.
I have created a package and in that I have two Data Flow task(DFT1 & DFT2).
DFT1 imports all the prof questions using Excel file(ProfQuestions.xls) as Flat file source.
DFT2 imports all the prof questions answer using another excel file(ProfQuestionAns.xls) as Flat file source.
In DFT2 excel file(ProQuestionAns.xls) I have QuestionID and many other columns and which can be referred to DFT1 excel file(ProQuestions.xls) having QuestionID, QuestionText column.

My Requirement is-
If there is at least one answer, the system shall display all questions, including questions without answer.
a) If there are no answers, no questions shall be displayed.

Let’s say I have got 4 questions answer out of 10 Questions in ProfQuestionAns.xls data files. The questions only having any answers will be there in this file but what about other remaining 6 Questions which will not be present in this ProfQuestionAns.xls file. How can I load those questions which are not there in DFT2 ProQuestionAns.xls data files but are there in DFT1 ProQuestions.xls data files? 
It looks like by calling DFT1 from DFT2 can work as I am not sure. Is it possible?
Any samples or solutions would be appreciated. Please Help me to achieve this.

Thanks
DK

Comment: What have you tried? Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please help for this,